# EXCEL/Google Sheets. Best way to SUM multiple VLOOKUP?

Tags: google-sheets, formula, vlookup

could you guys help me with a project. I was able to find a solution for my problem and the formula looks like this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E4;A8:B13;2;FALSE);0)+IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F4;A8:B13;2;FALSE);0)+IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G4;A8:B13;2;FALSE);0)
```

I have a category (e.g. Fruits) and need to import a sheet with different kind of fruits and non fruits. I use keywords which define what is a fruit and what not. I need to SUM all values which match to a keyword. My formula works but it will be more and more work when i need to add more keywords.

Are there a better way to realise this?

I build this example sheet for better understanding : )

[image]
[Spreadsheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OcJus2Gk__eIGGbP5LvyUFs6fPMKwb5HxCEVUb3nx9U/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you in advance : )

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(VLOOKUP(E4:G4; A8:B13; 2; )))
```

[image]

you can even use `E4:4` or `E4:G5` or `E4:5`

row-wise it would be:

```
=INDEX(BYROW(E4:G5; LAMBDA(x; SUM(IFNA(VLOOKUP(x; A8:B13; 2; ))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have to check your second attempt, seems to be a little bit more complicated but could be even more helpful : ).

Comment: @Player0 you didn't find the imposter?!

Comment: @Osm nice try but I am actually on dark mode so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Iuql.png

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM( IFERROR( VLOOKUP(E4:G4;A9:B;2;0))))
```

[image]

### Usign sumif

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(SUMIF(A9:A;"="&E4:G4;B9:B)))
```

[image]

### Xlookup

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(XLOOKUP(E4:G4;A9:A14;B9:B14;"";1)))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for multiple solutions. The first formula is exactly how i tried to make it work yesterday, but without the array function. I didnt know of the limitation and that i need to use arrayformula. That helps me a lot in understanding more stuff : )

Answer (score 0):

Us XLOOUP instead of IFERROR(VLOOKUP()) can shortens the formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(XLOOKUP($E4:4,$A$9:$A,$B$9:$B,0))
```